# Cannot fetch a rows from oracle (linked server) using openquery in sql server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, replication

I am rewriting a replication package between oracle and sql server. Currently the data is moved by ssis packages, but we move towards stored procedures because of better performance and easier maintenance.

I get the following error when I try to fetch rows from oracle using openquery in sql server.

""OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "" returned message "[oracle_db_name][ODBC 64bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Failed to retrieve data. Error ticket# kkfiquod1il1svbg21nxw[401]".
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "" returned message "[oracle_db_name][ODBC 64bit driver]Error in row.".
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "".""

The column that is causing the issue is an ntext column in oracle, I have tried to cast it in many ways, nothing.

Interestingly if I use LEFT(NVL(Column_Name, ''''), 4000) on the problematic column it returns some rows - the first 100 - or it returns lot more if I order my results by the id, but I can not get all.

When I located the 'last' id from the batch that did not fail and selected the next id's row the column was null just as some of the previous rows.

Is anyone ever experienced similar or have a solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you [edit] your question and add what versions of the ODBC driver, Oracle database, and SQL Server database.

Comment: Thank you, the versions are 10.00.18362.01 for oracle and 2017.175.01.01 for sql server.

Comment: That spoils what I was thinking could be the problem.  Oracle 12 optionally supports VARCHAR2 field lengths over 4000 characters, so I was wondering if your Oracle table had a length > 4000.  What _could_ be an issue is maybe you have a multi-byte character issue that is not being handled by the ODBC driver.  IE:  column length defined as 4000 characters, but some characters could use multiple bytes for a single character.  Try `select max(length(column_name)) from some_table;` to see if >= 4000.  And also try `LENGTHB` function that counts #/bytes.

Comment: I checked the max length already, it is ~3800, so that should not be the issue. Thank you Mark!